# Search with range with overlap

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have developed a search form in CodeIgniter that brings back results based on a range from a select box.

My issue is when the range overlaps it is not taking into account the overlap and does not return the correct results.

For example is the search range is 0-5000 it should bring back the the min value is that result is within that range.

Here is my controller code

```
if ($this->input->post('sqft')) {
                $_SESSION['sqft'] = $this->input->post('sqft');
                $explodeSquare = explode("-", $this->input->post('sqft'));
                $minSqaure = $explodeSquare[0];
                $maxSqaure = $explodeSquare[1];
                $this->db->where('minsize >=', $minSqaure);
                $this->db->where('maxsize <=', $maxSqaure);
                $this->db->order_by('id','DESC');
            }
```

In mysql I have items that are 300(min value) to 8000 (max value) so if searching between 0-5000 then it should return this item as the min value falls within the min size.

Is range the best way to work with this?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check for overlaps, then the logic should probably be:

```
$this->db->where('minsize <=', $maxSqaure);
$this->db->where('maxsize >=', $minSqaure);
```

Comment: This would then only search outside the range so would not work.

Comment: @user1857612 Test before tell.